# How to use Zomato API with React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am trying to use the Zomato API to search for resturants and right now I am trying to search console.log some data. In the [Zomato](https://developers.zomato.com/documentation#!/restaurant/search) documentation it gives me this Curl and Request URL

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "user-key: a725a13c0e61675a1eb07e3df050cd20" "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search"
```

and

```
https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search
```

I'm not exactly sure how to implement this. What I've tried to do so far is this

```
    const getResturants = () => {
  const axios = require('axios');
  axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search',
    headers: {
      "user-key": "a725a13c0e61675a1eb07e3df050cd20",
      "content-type": "application/json"
    }
  })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data.restaurants[0].restaurant.name);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
}
```

But I get back an error message.

Comment: Which error message are you getting?

Comment: Error: "Request aborted"
    createError createError.js:16
    handleAbort xhr.js:73

Comment: for me worked as expected, the issue is somewhere else

Comment: I'm not sure where to look for this issue

Answer (score 0):

What my suspect point is 1000 requests are allowed for a day and when it passes the limit the request will get throttled out. So make sure the request count is not exceeded.
I have used the below code to get the restaurant by finding the latitude and longitude and it worked. Below is my code to get the results from zomato api.

```
sendGetRestaurant = async () => {
    try {
        const resp = await axios.get('https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?lat='+this.state.Latitude+'&lon='+this.state.Longitude,{
            headers: {"user-key": "Access Key"}
          });
        console.log(resp.data);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

Below is the code to get the longitude and latitude.

```
 getLocation() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            (position) => {
                console.log("Latitude is :", position.coords.latitude);
                console.log("Longitude is :", position.coords.longitude);
                this.setState({
                    Latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                    Longitude: position.coords.longitude
                })
                this.sendGetRestaurant();
            },
            function (error) {
                console.error("Error Code = " + error.code + " - " + error.message);
            },
            {
                enableHighAccuracy: false,
                timeout: 10000,
                maximumAge: 10000
            }

        );
    }
```

Then I have called this inside the componentDidMount method.